Dynamic legend on QGIS Atlas
Each atlas page displays the buildings of a sector, symbolized by their respective subsectors. The attribute table shows all the buildings of the sector, using the relationship created in the project properties, where the sector and its buildings are linked.

Regarding symbolization, the subsectors are categorized based on the generation of rules, where the subsectors are linked to the variable @atlas_pagename. In this sense, I have to generate a rule for each subsector of all sectors.

The issue I'm facing is that I don't know how to control the legend to only display the subsectors of each sector. I've tried with the following expression but it doesn't work.
CASE WHEN @atlas_pagename = "sector" THEN 'symbol_label' ELSE null END

What you can do is the following:

use Categorized symbology instead of Rule-based.
hide the Categorized layer when not in the proper Atlas page by setting the Opacity to ("sector"=@atlas_pagename)*100
tick the Only show items in the current atlas feature in your Legend properties


Main sectors and subsectors to start with:


Apply this Opacity rule to all categories: ("sector"=@atlas_pagename)*100

You can do it the the first one, Delete and then Classify to automatically have this rule set for all Categories

Setup the Legend properties:

Change Atlas Item: it works!


It works! Nevertheless I don't get the difference between rule-based and specify the conditional opacity on categorized symbology.
As I understand "Only show items in the current atlas feature" condiition on legend properties should do the same in both cases.

I agree with your comment, it just seems like the legend part has trouble mixing dynamic legend and rules ( you might want to consider the Answer as accepted so that it shows as such)
